# Which is best table design for storing performance appraisal?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table to store employee performance appraisal.

I create table like this

```
id | employee| jobknowledge | Technical Skill  | Quality_work  |
1  | 1       |    4         |   3              |  4            |
```

or I also another design

```
id   | employee   | skilltype     |mark  |
1         1       | jobknowledge  |  4   |
2    |    1       | Technical_Skill| 3   |
```

This is only a sample skill type.The skill type more than 20 which is best design

Comment: well you can modify it a bit....create look up tables for each job knowledge and technical skill because one employee can have more than one skill...so i suggest you to create look up table for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second options it more better. Because when you try to this you have benefits:

- more least attributes column
- you can apply inheritance class of Skill.

you can create file skill_type.rb:

```
class SkillType < Employee
  def self.foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end
```

create child job_knowledge.rb

```
class JobKnowledge < SkillType
  def self.bar
    puts "#{self.foo}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create other tables for skills and job knowledge look up tables as below,

skills and employee look up table.

```
id | employee| skill        |
---|---------|--------------|
1  | 1       |    4         |
2  | 1       |    5         |
3  | 1       |    2         |
```

and same for job knowledge

```
id | employee| JobKnow.     |
---|---------|--------------|
1  | 1       |    4         |
2  | 1       |    2         |
3  | 1       |    10        |
```

so in future it will be easy for you query and by doing so you also maintain normalization.